# Unable to find a deserializer for the type

Tags: java, soap, salesforce, axis

I am trying update a Salesforce Object using Salesforce SOAP API.
Salesforce Update call fails to update the object and throws following exception:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Unable to find a deserializer for the type common.api.soap.wsdl.QueryResult Error Id: 322073137-21025 (-848058548)

at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)

at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)

at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)

at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)

at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)

at com.sforce.soap.enterprise.SforceServiceStub.update(SforceServiceStub.java:11289)

at com.dps.api.salesforce.crud.SalesforceCRUDImpl.updateAccount(SalesforceCRUDImpl.java:139)

at com.dps.api.crm.service.CRMServiceImpl.addEditPersonalInfoObject(CRMServiceImpl.java:109)

at com.dps.api.controller.ConfiguationController.updatePersonalInfo(ConfiguationController.java:145)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)

at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:874)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:757)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)

at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)

at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:154)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)

at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)

at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)

at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)

at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I've spent hours of searching on internet but nothing solves this problem!
Any idea how to get through it?

Comment: The Error Id looks like a Salesforce GACK response. Can you capture the outbound SOAP message and response? It looks like a problem with the way a QueryResult is being handled.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?  I am getting this error too now.

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never, right?  I spent a few hours troubleshooting this undescriptive error today until finally found the cause.

I was getting this message when trying to update a list of Opportunity records.  Turned out that this was because I was updating the same object that I got from a query, and one (or more) of the queried fields on that object were not writable.   I think it was either "recordtype.name" or "amount".  What I ended up doing was creating a new instance of Opportunity object for update purposes.

1) Query for the Opportunity records, including related lists, and certain non-writable fields.

2) Instead of updating the objects you get from the query in Step# 1, create a NEW List of NEW Opportunities for update purposes, and only populate the fields that you want to update.

```
ArrayList<Opportunity> queryOpps = apiCaller.executeQuery(queryString);
ArrayList<Opportunity> updateOpps = new ArrayList<Opportunity>();

for (Opportunity queryOpp : queryOpps) {
    // some condition for update
    if (queryOpp.getAmount() < queryOpp.getProjected_Revenue__c()) {

        // now, instead of adding the queryOpp to the update list,
        // create a new Opportunity object.
        Opportunity updateOpp = new Opportunity();
        updateOpp.setId(queryOpp.getId());
        updateOpp.setStageName("Needs Review");
        updateOpps.add(updateOpp);
    }
}

apiCaller.update(updateOpps);
```

​

Answer (score 1):

When you fetch parent and child object records using single SOQL statment having sub SOQL for child object and then you try to execute update on parent record then we get this error due to child record list present in parent record. The simple workaround is to set child record list(query result) to null inside parent object and then execute update on parent.